# MXE + CMake: How do you deploy statically linked Qt application on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, qt5, cross-compiling, mxe

I have cross-compiled my Qt application with `MXE` against a statically linked `Qt 5.11` on Ubuntu. I'm using MXE's `CMake` wrapper.

When I try to run my application on an actual Windows machine I get: `"This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized."`

The Qt deployment instructions don't directly say how this goes with statically linked Qt.

**Edit**: Seems that the easiest way to do this is with QMake as there are some problems with CMake and static Qt5 :(

Comment: Use the `windeployqt.exe ` utility for windows. You cannot do it in a regular CMD, it must be a developer's CMD.

Comment: @GKE That's not an option because I don't use Windows. I'm using MXE to cross-compile for Windows on Ubuntu. But I managed to make this work by using QMake instead of CMake with MXE.

Comment: Did you figure out a way to solve this? Would highly appreciate sharing your solution.

Comment: No, I didn't solve that. I gave up and have been using qmake for the Windows build, CMake for others.